# Call specific data from table

Tags: php, mysql

I forgot, I want to get a result to fetch from `projecten` by the table `pstatus` which has a value of 2 only, someone help me out?

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM projecten ORDER BY pstatus =2 only DESC");
```

needs to be

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM projecten WHERE pstatus = 2 ORDER BY pstatus DESC");
```

ok fixed thank you, you guys are so great, how can i filter multiple values in this case pstatus 0 and 1 only,..

Comment: Did you mean `WHERE pstatus = 2` ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM projecten WHERE pstatus =2`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: sorry lazy way thank you so much guys been a while,. you guys are great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WHERE` to select data where a condition is met.

`$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM projecten WHERE pstatus = 2");`

Comment: You will not need an `ORDER BY` as you are only selecting one `pstatus`

Answer (score 0):

You need  `WHERE` statement:

```
"SELECT * FROM projecten WHERE pstatus = 2"
```